# Xcode incorrectly set to use legacy build system

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm using Xcode 11.3 alongside MacOS 10.15.2. Even though the project settings are correctly set to `New Build System`, the orange hammer is still present in the activity view as pictured below.

[image]

According to [this doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes/build_system_release_notes_for_xcode_10) that means

> Projects configured to use the legacy build system will display an orange hammer icon in the Activity View.

This stops me from being able to use Swift Package Manager. I get an error stating `Packages are not supported when using the legacy build system, but the current workspace has it enabled.`

I've attempted to reinstall Xcode multiple times already with no luck. This happens for new projects and workspaces also. There doesn't appear to be a lot about how to manage this elsewhere.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Did you quit Xcode and delete the Derived Data folder? That sometimes helps.

Comment: Yeah I did. Gave it a completely fresh install. Deleted all directories related to Xcode

Comment: Are you using a Toolchain? — Is it stuck indexing?

Comment: Nope. I think I might have just performed a clean on the project just before I took the snapshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The codebase I was using had some setup steps which included

`defaults write com.apple.dt.Xcode UseModernBuildSystem -bool NO`

This affected any new projects that I created. Setting this to `YES` solved my problem.

Comment: How you have set the above

Comment: @sejn someone had set it in a build script